# Lens Metrics - Metrics to display with Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring

I have a k8s cluster set up with Virtual Box, a basic one, all nodes are using host-only INTERNAL-IP, and I am using Lens 2023.12.80831 to manage it

What I want is to have metrics for nodes and pods displayed on Lens (CPU, Memory ...)

I noticed that there is a menu named "Lens Metrics" under the "Settings", with three options
Prometheus (Enable bundled Prometheus metrics stack)
Kube State Metrics (Enable bundled kube-state-metrics stack)
Node Exporter (Enable bundled node-exporter-stack)

I selected to enable all of them, I see some pods installed in my cluster (prometheus-x, node-exporter-xxx, kube-state-metrics-xxx),

for the menu "Metrics", I selected the option "Auto Detect Prometheus", I got detailed information populated below
AUTO DETECTED PROMETHEUS DETAILS
Provider: Lens
Path:lens-metrics/services/prometheus:80

I don't see metrics displayed, "kubectl top" doesn't work either.

My question is, do I need to install the Prometheus and metrics-server separately? or Lens just has all of them installed and I might misconfig somewhere to get it displayed?

Can you help with a full guideline to have metrics displayed on Lens. I just want to try with built-in functionalities of Lens and Prometheus (not the Grafana or others)

Edited Dec 14: I figured out my issues because of that I am using VirtualBox Host-only Ethernet Adapter, I tried with a Bridge Adapter then I got no issues. So my question is how to fix the issue with Host-only?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider these possible solutions

1. You can manually configure Lens to connect to your Prometheus instance. From `Lens Settings \> Lens Metrics \> Prometheus (Custom)`. Specify the Prometheus endpoint URL.

   Ensure the IP address corresponds to the Prometheus pod accessible from Lens.
2. Check the Prometheus access that is running and accessible within the cluster. Use `kubectl get pods` and check the status of `prometheus-x` pods. Additionally, confirm firewall rules or network policies don't block access to the Prometheus port.
3. or you can reach out Lens support to further help you with configuring using the VirtualBox environment

Comment: I figured out I have to select "Lens" for the setting Metrics\Prometheus